# Not able to open file from servlet

Tags: file, servlets, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to open a pdf file from servlet in IE. it is giving error as `com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write`

### below is the code snippet

```
File file = new File("Desktop\\Workflow\\123456.pdf");
if(!file.exists()) {
    throw new ServletException("File doesn't exists on server.");
}
System.out.println("File location on server::"+file.getAbsolutePath());
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
String mimeType = ctx.getMimeType(file.getAbsolutePath());
response.setContentType(mimeType != null? mimeType:"application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"123456.pdf\"");
ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024];
int read=0;
while((read = fis.read(bufferData))!= -1) {
    System.out.println("read::"+read);    
    os.write(bufferData, 0, read);
}
os.flush();
os.close();
fis.close();
```

---

I am getting error at line `os.write(bufferData, 0, read);`

In Mozilla I am not getting any error but file is not opening here as well

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints to see where this is failing?  Is your buffer reading in the data as expected?

Comment: Do you get the same error if instead of setting the content type based on the mime type you force it to "application/octet-stream"?